# vba get weekday name from file created date?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the weekday name from a files created date:

```
Wk = WeekdayName(objFile.DateCreated)
```

So for instance, if my file has a file created date of 16/12/2016, then this will give a result of:

Friday

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
format(dateserial(2016,12,25),"DDDD")
```

Weekdayname relies on a weekday input, not a date.  so you could get that and use Weekdayname
  something like this

```
WeekdayName(Weekday(dateserial(2016,12,25),vbMonday))
```

Comment: any reason this wouldn't work? Seem to get an error? Wk = WeekdayName(Weekday(DatePart("ww", objFile.DateCreated, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)))

Comment: because you're trying to get the weekday of a weeknumber, answer to that is Monday to Sunday. :)

Comment: if i want to get the weekday name of objFile.DateCreated how could i do this?